# What is the best schema.org markup for a video platform?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

What google says:

- Multiple elements on a page: A video play page with related videos
  embedded in a separate section on the page. In this case, mark up the
  main video and related videos individually.
- Don't mark up content that is not visible to readers of the page.
- Carousel Page: Summary page + multiple full details pages

These statements are for me ambiguous. I have two different markups for the same pages. Which one is better and why? Or is there an other combination which is suitable?

**First version:**

Here is no markup which is not visible on the page. It is not possible two have 2 ItemLists in root level and hasPart takes no ItemList directly. This structure describes the whole page. Therefore GSTT shows only one item.

*Video page:*

```
ItemPage
    mainEntity: VideoObject
    breadcrumb: BreadCrumbList
    hasPart: WebPageElement
               mainEntity: ItemList (related videos)
                             ListItem (Link to video page)
                             ListItem
                             ...
    hasPart: WebPageElement
               mainEntity: ItemList (similar videos)
                             ListItem (Link to video page)
                             ListItem
                             ....
```

*Category page:*

```
VideoGallery
  breadcrumb: BreadCrumbList
  mainEntity: ItemList
      ListItem (Link to video page)
      ListItem 
      ...
```

**Second version:**

All VideoObjects are on the root level and the main video has all properties described. Even the VideoGallery is For VideoObject the description is mandatory, but I don't show the description for the related/similar videos to the user, but the main video. GSTT shows for every entry an item.

*Video page:*

```
VideoObject
    mainEntityOfPage (Link to VideoPage)
    - all possible properties

VideoObject (related video - just mandadory properties)
VideoObject (related video ...)
VideoObject
VideoObject
...
VideoObject (similar video - just mandadory properties)
VideoObject (similar video ...)
VideoObject
VideoObject
...
BreadcrumbList
```

*Category page:*

```
VideoGallery
VideoObject (category video)
VideoObject 
VideoObject
VideoObject
....
BreadCrumbList
```

Comment: Note that the "mandadory properties" are only required for getting one of Google’s rich results. As Google (as far as I know) doesn’t include related videos in the video rich result, you don’t have to provide the properties for these if you don’t want to. -- That said, is your question about the structured data for getting the Google rich result for videos, or do you ask generally about Schema.org best practices?

Comment: I already get rich results for my videos with just one VideoObject on the site, but I want to describe the whole webpage with schema.org for google.